# How can I use an interface method as a parameter of method type in Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi

I have one class instance and two references to it. There is one object reference (`aMII : TMyInterfaceImpl`) and one interface reference (`iMI : IMyInterface`).
When I use the object reference to assign one of its methods to a method type variable (`methodRef : TMyMethodRef`), it works fine.

But if I want to use the interface reference in the same situation, the compiler throws an error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(66): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMyMethodRef' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

The minimal example:

```
type
  TMyMethodRef = procedure of object;
  //TMyMethodRef = procedure of interface; // Invalid definition, just a desperate attempt

  IMyInterface = interface
    ['{BEA60A2B-C20F-4E02-A938-65DD4332ADB0}']
    procedure foo;
  end;

  TMyInterfaceImpl = class ( TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface )
    procedure foo;
  end;

procedure TMyInterfaceImpl.foo;
begin
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aMII : TMyInterfaceImpl;
  iMI : IMyInterface;
  methodRef : TMyMethodRef;
begin
  aMII := TMyInterfaceImpl.Create;
  iMI := aMII;
  methodRef := aMII.foo; // It compiles
  methodRef := iMI.foo; // It does not compile

end;
```

In my original source I have to use interfaces (I don't have the object references, because of the abstract factory design pattern : `function TMyFactory.createMyInterface : IMyInterface`).

And I have to use one of its methods as a callback function on some events (passed as a parameter to the setter method : `procedure TMyInterfaceImpl2.setOnEvent( onEvent_ : TMyMethodRef )`.

How can I do it? How can I assign one of the methods of an interface reference to a method type variable?

I know there is a solution to implement one another interface to access the object reference, but it does not secure (I could not be sure all the time the class implements both interfaces) and I don't want this solution:

```
type
  TMyMethodRef = procedure of object;

  IMyInterface = interface
    ['{BEA60A2B-C20F-4E02-A938-65DD4332ADB0}']
    procedure foo;
  end;

  TMyInterfaceImpl = class;

  IInstanceAccessor<T> = interface
    ['{61E36FF2-A9D3-4B46-BAE8-217CBE7A1F18}']
    function getInstance : T;
  end;

  TMyInterfaceImpl = class ( TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface, IInstanceAccessor<TMyInterfaceImpl> )
    procedure foo;
    function getInstance : TMyInterfaceImpl;
  end;

procedure TMyInterfaceImpl.foo;
begin
end;

function TMyInterfaceImpl.getInstance : TMyInterfaceImpl;
begin
  result := self;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iMI : IMyInterface;
  aMII : TMyInterfaceImpl;
  methodRef : TMyMethodRef;
begin
  iMI := TMyInterfaceImpl.Create;
  aMII := ( iMI as IInstanceAccessor<TMyInterfaceImpl> ).getInstance;
  methodRef := aMII.foo;
end;
```

Comment: Create a record type that holds a reference to the interface. On that record type implement a method that calls the interface method. Or use a class instead of a record if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan David If you create an answer I will accept it. Uwe solution works fine as well but it seems to me a better one. The record type allocation/destroy is automatically do, not as like the object instances.

Comment: Uwe's answer is good. It's the same as mine. Sometimes record is better. Sometimes class is better. All depends. For instance if you want the wrapper to outlast the function which declares it then a record isn't so great. The concept is what matters.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After an attempt in my original like environment  I realized that I have to store the record/adapter instances... The better solution I think if I make a depencency between the interfaces and pass the have to call interface itself as a parameter. :( Or I derive it from an ancestor interface, which contains just the callback method and pass that one as a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that.

What you can do is declare an adapter class with such a method and use that method as the callback.

```
type
  TMyInterfaceAdapter = class
  private
    FIntf: IMyInterface;
  public
    procedure Foo;
    property Intf: IMyInterface read FIntf write FIntf;
  end;

procedure TMyInterface.Foo;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(FIntf), 'no interface assigned');
  FIntf.Foo;
end;
```

Comment: This is a working solution. Thanks for your time and energy. I accepted and upvoted it. But the one posted by David (just as a comment yet) seems to me a better one. The record allocation/destroy do automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not wish to maintain adapter classes and to manage their life-times, and are free to change to `TMyMethodRef = System.SysUtils.TProc`, you may also use anonymous methods:

```
var
  Impl: TMyInterfaceImpl;
  Intf: IMyInterface;
  MethodRef: TMyMethodRef;
begin
  Impl := TMyInterfaceImpl.Create;
  MethodRef := Impl.Foo;
  MethodRef;
  Intf := Impl; // Be sure to capture it!
  MethodRef := procedure begin Intf.foo; end;
  MethodRef;
end;
```

This works in the background somewhat similar to [what you described in your own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154237/#comment91260602_52154237). Also, generally and as you are already using interfaces, if possible switch to consistently using interfaces.